# Scrapy json output file adding unnessary square bracket

Tags: python, json, scrapy

Scrapy is outputting a flawed json file. When I try to work with the said json file, with

```
import json
```

I am confronted with this error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 311 column 94 (char 28466)
```

This is caused be an unnecessary square bracket being added to the front of the json file.

JSON file will look like this

```
[[{"city": "New York", "state": "New York", "rank": "1\n", "population": ["8,622,698\n"]},
{"city": "Los Angeles", "state": "California", "rank": "2\n", "population": ["3,999,759\n"]}]`
```

I am using this command to crawl:

```
scrapy crawl wiki -o items.json
```

When I manually remove the square bracket, it runs normally. This is the other python script:

```
import json

with open ("items1.json", "r") as read_file:
data = json.load(read_file)
print(type(data))
```

**edit**

the spider in question

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`


import scrapy


class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):    
    name = "wiki"    
    allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org"]

    start_urls = ('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population')

    def parse(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('//table')[4]
        trs = table.xpath('.//tr')[1:]
        for tr in trs:
            rank = tr.xpath('.//td[1]/text()').extract_first()
            city = tr.xpath('.//td[2]//text()').extract_first()
            state = tr.xpath('.//td[3]//text()').extract()[1]
            population = tr.xpath('.//td[4]//text()').extract()

            yield {
                'rank':rank,
                'city': city,
                'state': state,
                'population':population
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide all the code? Perhaps you use custom pipelines for the formation of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there is an unwanted `[` in your JSON, but I did run your code and it worked as expected. Are you sure you aren't mixing up `items1.json` and `items.json`? Both are mentioned in your question.

Besides that, I notice the Wikipedia URL is wrong but I believe it is just a typo.